# Is it possible to create auto generated id in mysql view?

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE VIEW EMAIL_CAMP AS SELECT DISTINCT(UPT.EMAIL_ID),
'N' AS FLAG FROM ITEM_MASTER_TABLE
IMT INNER JOIN ORDER_DETAIL_TABLE ODT
ON IMT.ITEM_ID = ODT.ITEM_ID
INNER JOIN ORDER_MASTER_TABLE OMT
ON ODT.ORDER_ID = OMT.ORDER_ID 
INNER JOIN PAYMENT_TRANSACTION_TABLE PT
ON OMT.ORDER_ID = PT.ORDER_ID
INNER JOIN USER_PROFILE_TABLE UPT
ON OMT.USER_ID = UPT.USER_ID
WHERE PT.COUPON_CODE = 'ABCD';
```

just I want have one more column in my `view(EMAIL_CAMP)`, which should be auto generated one, could any one help me regarding this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create it in the view, but you can add one every time you query it, like so:

```
select @row := @row+1 as `id`, v.* 
  from EMAIL_CAMP v,
    (select @row := 0) q
```

And this will give every row a numeric id.